# Email Disappears between IMAP and POP

Tags: imap, pop3, outlook-2016

I have a client who has an online store, and receives order notifications by email.

Their order emails are flowing into their mailbox on the server, but never show up in Outlook.

Their Outlook is configured as POP, I have reset the mailbox password to ensure no other connections, there are no rules created.
If I turn off POP auto-delete, I see the order notification email in the IMAP inbox, but (even with search) I cannot locate it in Outlook.

What else could it be/what else can I check?

Comment: Check the rules for incoming emails on outlook, I think by mistake someone added a rule to delete the emails that is coming

Comment: @TalalAl-Khalifa there are no rules set up in Outlook

Answer (score -1):

Look at the server logs and see if there are other devices popping the account. It sounds to me there is another device (maybe a cellphone)/messing things up. The log file might also provide other clues

Alternatively change the password and see if the problem goes away. Also consider migrating from POP to IMAP on all your devices.

Comment: Tried password change, issue continued. Only the one PC with Outlook has the new password. Nothing remarkable in the logs, just normal POP connections.